# Can an Astropath Trascendent use or burn a Fate Point to save himself from a 100 roll of Perils of the Warp

Tags: rogue-trader, character-death

The worst thing that can happen to a Psyker in Rogue Trader is to roll in the Perils of the Warp table. Among them, the 100 roll states:

> 100 Destruction: The psyker is immediately and irrevocably destroyed. He is sucked screaming into the warp, never to be seen again or consumed utterly by hellfire. There is a 50% chance, that a daemonic entity appears in the psyker’s place

However... fate points can be burned to basically cheat death:

> Sometimes though, Fate may not be enough to save the Explorer from a terrible and final death. In these cases, the player can burn a Fate Point, permanently reducing the Explorer’s Fate Point pool by one. However, doing so means that the Explorer survives whatever awful calamity just occurred, albeit only barely.

Could a psyker spend a fate point to re-roll in case he rolled a 100? In case he couldn't, or he had ran out of fate points, could a psyker avoid being uttery obliterated by burning a fate point?

Comment: I don't see why not, though that doesn't mean he has to come out of the situation unscathed. I'd see it as perfectly reasonable to still roll the chance to summon a daemonic entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key line is "Spending one Fate Point allows for one of the following:... Re-roll  a failed test once. The results of the re-roll are final." This means he cannot spend the fate point to re-roll on the *Psychic Phenomena* or *Perils of the Warp* tables. Those are not tests but effects rolls. He can however re-roll doubles on a **Focus Power Test** to avoid having to roll on the *Psychic Phenomena* table at all.

As you pointed out the rules also say he can burn a fate point to avoid his oncoming demise. Note that it says they survive but only barely. Given what just happened to the psyker there is a lot of room here for some GM magic. A demon appears in his place and shunts him aside 2d10 meters and doing the equivalent amount of fall damage, appears alive but on a demon world inside the eye of terror, or maybe goes into the rift but comes out in the future (right as the party sends the demon packing or needs him most).

Comment: So he is not "immediately and irrevocably destroyed". That bit of the description is what bugs me.

Comment: I would view the "immediately and irrevocably destroyed" text in a similar light as some of the death effects on the critical hit tables. Burning the fate point happens outside of time and re-writes reality.